# Which one is better towards getting MCPD as to a freshman, .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I am a graduated java programmer with basic knowledge of C#. I am planning to learn C# and get MCPD certificates on .NET. Which one is better for me to learn, 3.5 or 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.0 seems more of a better approach. 4.5 is around the corner but is going to be more of an addon of 4.0 while 3.5 is an addon to 2.0. Going for 4.0 exams are going to last longer for you and your career.

However be sure to also take a look at what each older framework brought to the market. 2.0 for example was a massive powerup since 1.x which introduced quite a lot of very interesting stuff to the framework and the technology stacks that build upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I would start earlier, at .NET 2.0. Once you have a fuller understanding of C# at that level, then start researching the new things introduced in .NET 3.5. Once you're comfortable with those, graduate to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the ".Net 2.0" comment, much as I'd agree with the importance of understanding J2SE 1.2 (independent of Java 5, 6 or 7)>

Having said that, I strongly suggest the smartest thing you can do is focus on .Net 4.0.

Don't even worry about .Net 3.5 ... but DO worry about WPF (GUI) and WCF (infrastructure).